# am i looking for average here

Tags: c#, sql, statistics

I have a note field that I'm trying to determine a cut off length to display.

I have some numbers

**Note Length** and **# of Notes with that length**

How do I come up with a good average? Do I need more information?

Thanks,
rod.

Comment: I think WE may need more information. "Average" has a precise mathematical meaning. Do you mean "typical length"? I'm guessing that what you really care about is "what is the smallest field size that will not cause me to lose information", and if so, that would seem to be somewhat dependent on the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use an average, I would do a distribution graph first and find out the distribution of values..and then adjust the percentage cut-off to whatever goals you are trying to accomplish.

An average can be really skewed by a few outlying lengths. You may find out, for example, that 95% of your notes are under xxx length, and if you can live with xxx, then 95% of your notes will be fully displayed.

Comment: That's exactly where Standard Deviation can be your friend. :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to do this dynamically? Usually these kinds of decisions are driven more by UI/usability concerns, than average length of data.

E.g., for a note preview in a tooltip or table, I might choose to use a max of 50 characters, even though a note might be as big as 4,000 characters.

Comment: If you're focusing on "...a cut off length to display", then I would focus on what you *can* display (or call it "can fit into your display"), not what you *have* to display.

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts:

1. If the maximum length isn't too bad, just use maximum.
2. If you're going to do the average, you might want to eliminate the items that are one or two standard deviations out.  A couple really long (or really short) notes can really skew your average.

Answer (score 0):

The Average (Arithmetic Mean) would be (Note Length * # Notes with length) / Total # notes of all lengths